# Docker run bash script, then remove container

Tags: docker

Is there a way I can run a bash script inside a container and then remove the container, everything in a single line? The script should be able to write to the folder where it's currently at.

I've tried

```
docker run --rm -ti ubuntu:trusty bash -c 'source runme.sh'
```

but bash can't find the file, I'm assuming because the container doesn't have access to the folder where the script is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the script is not available inside the container, you need to mount the script as a volume inside the container:

```
$ cat << EOF > sample_script.sh
echo 'Hello, world'
EOF
```

Run the docker container as follows (here, `/path/to/sample_script.sh` is the path in the host):

```
$ docker run -v /path/to/sample_script.sh:/sample_script.sh \
  --rm ubuntu bash sample_script.sh

Hello, world
```

The container will be removed after execution. Note you don't need to run it interactively, standard output will be displayed.

The [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/volume-shared-filesystems) reference has the details about using volumes in this way.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is execute a script you could just use bash to read the script from stdin.

```
sample_script.sh < docker run --rm -i ubuntu bash -c 'source /dev/stdin'
```

Comment: `cat sample_script.sh | docker run -i ...` worked for me